# Calculating determinant using submatrices

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Suppose $M$ is a $n\times n$ matrix, I want to show that
\begin{align*}
\text{det}\left(I+xM\right)=\sum_{U\subset\{1,\cdots,n\}}x^{\#U}\text{det}(M_{U}),
\end{align*}
where $I$ denotes the identity matrix and $M_{U}$ denotes the submatrix obtained by keeping only the rows and columns of $M$ that are in the set $U$. I guess I need to expand it as a sum of permutations, but I wonder exactly how. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $M=(m_1,m_2,\dots,m_n)$, $I=(e_1,e_2,\dots,e_n)$

Then by column expansion, we have
\begin{align*}
|I+xM|&=|e_1+xm_1\quad e_2+xm_2\quad \dots\quad e_n+xm_n|\\
&=|e_1\quad e_2+xm_2\quad \dots\quad e_n+xm_n|+x|m_1\quad e_2+xm_2\quad \dots\quad e_n+xm_n|\\
&=\dots\\
&=\sum_{U\subset\lbrace 1,2,\dots,n\rbrace}x^{\#U}|p_1\quad p_2\quad \dots\quad p_n|,\text{ where } p_i=\begin{cases}
m_i,i\in U\\ 
e_i,i\notin U\\ 
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

By Laplace expansion(or simply column expansion), $|p_1\quad p_2\quad \dots\quad p_n|=\det(M_U)$, i.e.,
$$\det(I+xM)=\sum_{U\subset\lbrace 1,2,\dots,n\rbrace}x^{\#U}\det(M_U)$$